# ImportError: cannot import name 'nlp' from 'pycaret'

Tags: python, nlp

He estado tratando de importar el módulo "nlp" de la biblioteca pycaret en un cuaderno de colab, pero he obtenido el siguiente error: ***ImportError: cannot import name 'nlp' from 'pycaret' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pycaret/**init**.py).***

Los pasos que he realizado son los siguientes:

Abrí un cuaderno en Colab.

Instalé la biblioteca pycaret: ***!pip install pycaret[full]***

Importé el módulo nlp: ***from pycaret import nlp***

Finalmente he obtenido el error ya mencionado al inicio.

Answer (score 0):

Los módulos **NLP** y **ARules** fueron retirados de PyCaret desde la versión 3.0. Ver [notas de la versión](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/releases/tag/3.0.0).

Soluciones serían:

- Actualizar el código a los nuevos módulos.
- Usar una versión anterior de pycaret

```
pip install pycaret==2.3.10
```

[*Nota*] Probé lo anterior en un **venv** con Python 3.10 y, al menos en mi caso, me dio una serie de errores de compilación con las dependencias (numpy, pandas, scipy, ...). Es posible que las mismas también requieran versiones muy específicas. Tendrás que averiguar por tu cuenta esto.

[*Edit*] [Investigando](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74765966/1545868), dice que Pycaret 2.3.10 no soporta python 3.10, así que tendrás que intentar con una versión anterior de Python.